# Talend Studio fails to generate code

Tags: user-controls, java-8, java-7, talend

I'm developing some new Components in a brand new installation of Talend Open Studio for ESB version 6.3.0 and when I try to execute a job where there's only one of my new component, I get this message:

[image: My Job]

***Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted***

I'm running Studio on  a Linux Mint machine, with Java 8 as default jvm, and with Java 7 jdk installed.

Everything in Studio is configured to use version 7 of Java, in the General references
[image: General Prefs]
[image: Installed JRE]

and in the config of the COMPONENT_PROJECT.

[image: COMPONENT_PROJECT config]

**What more do I have to set up to be able to use Java 7 in my Components?**

PS: Everything else works perfectly in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For Talend 5 the java JDK had to be installed when working with esb/web services.

Refer to the documentation:
https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Requiring+a+JDK+installation+to+build+jobs+starting+from+version+6.0

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think this is not the issue. Any other job that doesn't involve Java 1.7 specifics run without any troubble. The compiler is not complaining about the JDK, it's complaining about its version.

Comment: In any case, just for the sake of it, I followed the indications on the link you provided, removed all the JRE and only left one JDK  *(java-7-openjdk-amd64)* and tried again: same results.

Comment: have you tried oracle JDK? Maybe it doesn't like openjdk?

Comment: try deleting your workspace (export any items to zip file first for back up) and then reopen Talend.  It will create a new work space.  Then import your items back in, rebuild and run.  That simple solution has solved many compile and execution problems for my team, might solve yours.